# filter jqgrid with multiple "and" and "or" conditions

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I want to filter jQGrid using below search criteria

```
Name="Mark" and Age=25 and (city="NY" or city="FL") and (company="xyz" or company="zyx")
```

below is my search string

```json
{
    "groupOp": "AND",
    "rules": [{
        "field": "Name",
        "op": "eq",
        "data": "Mark"
    }, {
        "field": "Age",
        "op": "eq",
        "data": "25"
    }],
    "groups": [{
        "groupOp": "OR",
        "rules": [{
                "field": "city",
                "op": "eq",
                "data": "NY"
            },
            {
                "field": "city",
                "op": "eq",
                "data": "FL"
            }
        ],
        "groups": [{
            "groupOp": "OR",
            "rules": [{
                    "field": "company",
                    "op": "eq",
                    "data": "xyz"
                },
                {
                    "field": "company",
                    "op": "eq",
                    "data": "zyx"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

and

```js
postData: {
    filters: above string
},
```

but this search is not working. please help

Comment: Please include the output you get with these options.

Comment: There is some sensitive data so i can not share that

Comment: {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[
{"field":"city","op":"in","data":"NY,FL"}
  ,{"field":"company","op":"in","data":"xyz,zyx"}]} i used in operator also but "in" is not working

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an error in the last `"groups"` part. The correct filter should looks like

```json
{
    "groupOp": "AND",
    "rules": [
        { "field": "Name", "op": "eq", "data": "Mark" },
        { "field": "Age",  "op": "eq", "data": "25" }
    ],
    "groups": [
        {
            "groupOp": "OR",
            "rules": [
                { "field": "city", "op": "eq", "data": "NY" },
                { "field": "city", "op": "eq", "data": "FL" }
            ],
            "groups": []
        },
        {
            "groupOp": "OR",
            "rules": [
                { "field": "company", "op": "eq", "data": "xyz" },
                { "field": "company", "op": "eq", "data": "zyx" }
            ],
            "groups": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Additionally, I'd strictly recommend you to include **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

If you really use "free jqGrid" (not an old jqGrid in version <=4.7), then you can use `"IN"` operator with local dataset. The value should be comma-separated list of values and the

```json
{
    "groupOp": "AND",
    "rules": [
        { "field": "Name",     "op": "eq", "data": "Mark" },
        { "field": "Age",      "op": "eq", "data": "25" },
        { "field": "city",     "op": "eq", "data": "NY,FL" },
        { "field": "company",  "op": "eq", "data": "xyz,zyx" }
    ]
}
```

Additionally free jqGrid allows to replace the default comma separator (which could be included in some company names) to any alternative symbol defined by jqGrid option `inFilterSeparator`.

Comment: {"groupOp": "AND", "rules": [
        { "field": "Name", "op": "eq", "data": "Mark" },
        { "field": "Age",  "op": "eq", "data": "25" }
    ],"groups": [{ "groupOp": "OR",
            "rules": [{ "field": "city", "op": "eq", "data": "NY" },
                { "field": "city", "op": "eq", "data": "FL" } ],
            "groups": []
        },
        {
            "groupOp": "OR", "rules": [
                { "field": "company", "op": "eq", "data": "xyz" },
                { "field": "company", "op": "eq", "data": "zyx" }],
            "groups": []
        } ]]

Comment: i am using 4.7 JQgrid version

Comment: @SrikarNaidu: You should provide **the demo**, which reproduces the problem. By the way, I get the filter, which I included in my answer, from working demo just replacing the column names and values. In other ways, the filter do works on free jqGrid 4.15.4 and the first one should work in the retro version 4.7. I suppose that you use some other jqGrid options, which you didn't posted, which are the origin of your problem. I can't help you without having the demo.

Comment: @SrikarNaidu: By the way, the filter which you posted in your first comment is **wrong**. Two latest characters of the filter are `]]` instead of `]}` (see my answer).

Comment: I sent email from sreekanth_kurakula@hotmail.com

Comment: I am using 4.14.1 version of JQGRID, but to enable multi select dropdown i am refering @*Compatable js for Check box drop down feature*@, /jqGrid-master/js/4.8.0/jquery.jqgrid.src.js